# Images not showing up

Tags: graphics, diagrams

I have a problem with images not showing up. The latex recognises them (see screenshot) but doesn't generate them to pdf document. They are in the same folder. I tried including image extensions and with the part that is commented.
The images are .png.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft,pdftex]{article}    
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}   

%\graphicspath{name/Dropbox/projectProgramming/graphs/}

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{avgP}
\caption{Average}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What format is the `avgP` file?

Comment: @egreg based on the screenshot, my guess is PNG.

Comment: @egreg all the images are .png

Comment: The cause is the `draft` option. The `pdftex` option should ***never*** be passed to either `\documentclass` or `graphicx` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by removing pdftex and draft from documentclass.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
```